# Read and display JSON returned from Google Maps API in a View of Eclipse RCP

Tags: json, google-maps, eclipse-rcp

I am developing a desktop application with Eclipse RCP using Google Directions API, where giving source and destination would result in directions.

But when I use this API "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal" I am returned a JSON file to save. But I need to display the directions in a view inside a perspective. How can I display it in a view?

Also, I am currently using a Browser class to display the whole browser in a view. Can anyone tell me if it is possible to only display Maps in the view instead of the whole browser instance?

Answer (score 0):

Add your browser View to your perspective. You need to provide origin and destination and excute java script to make browser to get the route information. In any case if you need to inform the RCP view once the page is loaded, you could use `BrowserFucntion` class.